# sql query returning whole column of data

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a VB.net program that parses a set of variables into a sub that I use to communicate with an Access Database.
The query string reads:

```
SELECT ID FROM cbRooms WHERE @condition
```

@condition is given a value with the code:

```
.Parameters.AddWithValue("@condition", dbCondition)
```

Where dbCondition is, in this case:

```
H_Block=True
```

When I run this query within Access directly, I get the expected data back, which is a set of numbers, that have a ticked box in Access

However, when I run that same code in Visual Studio, it just returns the whole column, regardless of whether the tick box is true or not

It's been a while since i've written something in VB, so i'm quite rusty, and therefore the problem is likely a simple oversight on my part

Here is the code for the sql access function:

```
Public Function sqlSelect(ByVal dbCol As String, ByVal dbTable As String, ByVal dbCondition As String)


    'Creating the sqlCmd string to sent as an SQL request to the Database
    Dim sqlCmd As String
    'Creating a new connection to the database
    Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

    'Setting the value for the sqlCmd string, with several "@" parameters
    sqlCmd = "SELECT " & dbCol & " FROM " & [dbTable] & " WHERE @condition;"
    'Running the Connect Sub routine to interact with the database
    Connect(conn)

    Using conn
        Using dbEvent As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
            With dbEvent
                'sets the connection used by the current instance of OleDB usng the conn string
                .Connection = conn
                'Sets how the .CommandType is interpreted
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                'Sets the sqlCmd string that will be sent
                .CommandText = sqlCmd
                'Setting the "@" parameters in the sqlCmd string using values parsed into the sub routine
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@condition", dbCondition)
            End With

            Try
                'Opening connection to the database
                conn.Open()
                'Creating the _sqlRead Reader used to read the data coming from the database
                Dim sqlReader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
                sqlReader = dbEvent.ExecuteReader()

                'Creates a list that will store the values returned to the Search.vb class
                Dim returnVals As New List(Of Integer)

                Do While sqlReader.Read = True
                    returnVals.Add(sqlReader(dbCol))
                Loop

                Return returnVals

            Catch ex As Exception
                'Opens a message box showing the current error
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error Message")
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

And Here is the code for the combo box that calls the AccessSQL.vb:

```
Public Sub cbBlock_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbBlock.SelectedIndexChanged
    Select Case cbBlock.Text
        Case "H Block"
            cbRoom.Items.Clear()
            Dim listOfRoomsInBlock As New List(Of Integer)
            listOfRoomsInBlock = sqlSelect("ID", "cbRooms", "H_Block=True")
            For x = 0 To listOfRoomsInBlock.Count - 1
                cbRoom.Items.Add(listOfRoomsInBlock(x))
            Next
        Case "Tech Block"
            cbRoom.Items.Clear()
            Dim listOfRoomsInBlock As New List(Of Integer)
            listOfRoomsInBlock = sqlSelect("ID", "cbRooms", "T_Block=True")
            For x = 0 To listOfRoomsInBlock.Count - 1
                cbRoom.Items.Add(listOfRoomsInBlock(x))
            Next

    End Select
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:
The SQL, when run in VB returns [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWuL9.jpg) into the combo box I'm trying to populate
The 1 - 13 values at the bottom is what I'm expecting, whereas the 14 - 30 is not. My thinking is that my parameterisation is never actually using the condition I set above.

However, when I run that same, [expected query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37n1T.png), inside Access, I get the right [values returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOKVS.png)

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Make it *easy* for someone to help you - dont make them go elsewhere to see the code related to your problem.

Comment: I'd like to see what SELECT ID FROM cbRooms WHERE H_Block=@condition and .Parameters.AddWithValue("@condition", True) will give